# Disable elemts of dataTable in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any way to disable all the elements of the dataTable in primefaces. I have chekBoxes, inputText etc in the dataTable. I tried with setting editable to false but didn't succeed.

Comment: How?When?Where do you want to disable the elements? Please, give more details.

Comment: There are two types of users. One can just view the dataTable and other can edit the elements of dataTable like entering text in inputText or selecting checkBox etc.

Comment: Ok, it seems easy. Put your code with the work done so far and people could help you.

Comment: As to your `editable="false"` attempt, did you check the showcase example how it should actually be used? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: Do you want to lock the whole `p:dataTable`?  If so, [`p:blockUI`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @BalusC I tried with editable="false" editMode="cell". But no success!!!

Comment: I believe you missed `<p:cellEditor>` in the example. And, you don't need to yell. I'm deaf.

Comment: @BalusC lol didn't mean in that way. Sorry if my comment was harsh. Kinda frustrated right now.

Comment: Then improve your initial question. With code...